# How to match logged in Facebook user via the Javascript API against his URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello fellow developers.

I have been battling for the last several weeks with the following.

I want to get the logged user authenticated via FB, his profile URL.

Simple. But it's impossible to get it automatically.

When the user logs in, an FBID gets generated, when using https://www.facebook.com/?profile_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx it gets redirected to the user's profile, https://www.facebook.com/username - Tada! Data accuracy is 100%.

I have tried to get this FB username, but via graph is not allowed without permission which simply, works similar to the profile_id - is not the actual username. I believe with the whole Cambridge stuff, this was removed.

My next tackle was, trying to do a CURL request - I wrote a function which gets the last URL of the redirect. This fails, due to facebook responding as 'Unsupported Browser'.

I tried passing different types of headers ( User Agent, Canonical, SSL ) but none of them work. Data accuracy is down to practically, 0%.

My last option was to use a comment plugin, within the comment plugin - right next to the text area, I see the link to my profile - exactly how I want it. What I have tried to do is get the source of the iframe and look towards where the FB Username displays and feed it back to my db. I would then match the FBID to that, and I have what I want. Data accuracy with this method would be somewhere in the 75% / 80% range.

But, that didn't work either. Several reasons, 1- the FB Iframe doesn't seem to keep a constant class attach to elements - so I am afraid that would not last long. 2- the iframe itself doesn't have an ID to have Javascript console.log at least the content. 3- the timing is very irregular, although this isn't a real issue since I could run a timeout function after say 10 seconds of the user being logged in, but what I am referring is - I need to get the FBID first, to match it with the FB user name. It's not a stable but rather fragile way. Data accuracy is down to 50% to less stable.

So I am stuck, I don't know how I could match the FBID to the username without FB Graph.

My very very very last option would be, a comment box where the user needs to type a unique code that's generated for him/her - then that message is received and I then manually verify it, an account would be verified.

But this would be painful devs, I want it to be done automatically. I feel there is a way, but I am stuck.

Does anyone dare to suggest how I can achieve this? Even if is far far fetch ( even if it comes from Canto Bight planet ) ....

*I bow down
*I say thank you!

Comment: there is no way to get the username anymore, since a very long time (even before the cambridge analytica stuff. what´s the point of matching an ID with the profile url anyway? what´s the use case? maybe you are doing something that could be done in a different way? what you are trying right now is just not possible and scraping is not allowed on facebook.

Comment: btw, i removed some tags, because fql is gone since several years, and your question is not related to javascript or the js sdk.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The last APP I did with FB was like 3 years ago... so I am rusty. There is a point, specifically for the purpose of the app itself, I need to match a URL within the system to when someone logs in to the site.

Comment: ok, but there is no way, i´m afraid. username access is gone, it would be pointless to implement that redirected url if it would still be possible to access the real one. you can only let users enter their url on their own, but there is no api to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, I´m afraid. `username` access is gone, it would be pointless to implement that redirected url if it would still be possible to access the real one. You can only let users enter their url on their own, but there is no API to get it.